# Convert CSV to Shapefile using GDAL_translate

Tags: shapefile, gdal, csv, gdal-translate

I have some CSV files that need to be converted to ESRI shapefile.
These files are built like explained in the section **"Building line geometries"** from the [GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html).
For example one file can be like this:

```
> head river_xy2.csv                                                                                      
way_id,pt_id,x,y
1,1,11.836,44.829
1,2,11.827,44.829
1,3,11.818,44.829
1,4,11.809,44.838
1,5,11.8,44.847
1,6,11.791,44.856
1,7,11.782,44.856
1,8,11.773,44.856
1,9,11.764,44.856
```

GDAL understands this, for example I can do:

```
ogrinfo river_xy2.csv -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT way_id, MakeLine(MakePoint(CAST(x AS float),CAST(y AS float))) FROM river_xy2 GROUP BY way_id"
```

And I get a nice list of OGRFeatures in output. However, how can I save that to a shapefile? If I try to use GDAL_translate:

```
> gdal_translate -of "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs EPSG:4326 river_xy2.csv river_xy2.shp
ERROR 4: `river_xy2.csv' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

While if I remove the first row I get an error after the first feature:

```
ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 549, change of Y direction
```

EDIT:
It looks like I can do:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT way_id, MakeLine(MakePoint(CAST(x AS float),CAST(y AS float))) FROM river_xy GROUP BY way_id" -a_srs EPSG:4326 river_xy.shp river_xy.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

gdal_translate is for raster data, you want to use **ogr2ogr**. Yes, the command names are a complete mess.

Comment: Would you please be able to elaborate on this? At the present state this feels more like a comment than an answer. EDIT: I guess I should do `ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT way_id, MakeLine(MakePoint(CAST(x AS float),CAST(y AS float))) FROM river_xy2 GROUP BY way_id" river_xy2.shp river_xy2.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on bugmenot123's answer, say you had a .csv file called xy.csv with the following contents:

```
X        Y
-95.3942 28.7701
-95.356  28.7644
```

create the shapefile's database file with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.dbf xy.csv
```

Create a text file that will be the 'virtual' shapefile (for this example, name it out.vrt) having the following contents:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="out">
    <SrcDataSource>xy.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>xy</SrcLayer>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Create the new shapefile (.shp) from the virtual shapefile (VRT) as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.shp out.vrt
```

Comment: What if I want a shapefile with the lines? Is it sufficient to use wkbLine? If `ogrinfo` understands the data, why can't it produce a readable output directly?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. : )    Your command:             
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT way_id, MakeLine(MakePoint(CAST(x AS float),CAST(y AS float))) FROM head_river_xy2 GROUP BY way_id" head_river_xy2.shp head_river_xy2.csv  works quite nicely to convert a csv file of points / coordinates to a line shapefile !

Comment: Unfortunately as you can see from the updated question it seeems to have some issues... I'll test with the solution provided by @Antonio Falciano

Comment: Do you have more than one way_id? It looks like it is connecting all the lines which may indicate they share the same way_id since they were aggregated/grouped by it. In my test here I added another (fake/testing) way_id to your example like so                                                         
way_id,pt_id,x,y
1,1,11.836,44.829
1,2,11.827,44.829
1,3,11.818,44.829
1,4,11.809,44.838
1,5,11.8,44.847
1,6,11.791,44.856
1,7,11.782,44.856
1,8,11.773,44.856
1,9,11.764,44.856
2,10,12.836,45.829
2,11,12.827,45.829
2,12,12.818,45.829
2,13,12.809,45.838

Comment: I might have found the problem, I'll report back. I think the file was not correctly formatted by those who produced it.

Comment: Indeed there was a problem in one input file I was using for the test. Thanks.